# Installing gcc on alpine linux (BAD archive)

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I get the error sometimes, not always.

Why does this happen?

If I run it again, it will be alright.

```
Step 3/14 : RUN apk add --no-cache git gcc mariadb-dev musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Running in 591d6e97ff53
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/26) Installing binutils (2.32-r0)
(2/26) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
(3/26) Installing isl (0.18-r0)
(4/26) Installing libgomp (8.3.0-r0)
(5/26) Installing libatomic (8.3.0-r0)
(6/26) Installing libgcc (8.3.0-r0)
(7/26) Installing mpfr3 (3.1.5-r1)
(8/26) Installing mpc1 (1.1.0-r0)
(9/26) Installing libstdc++ (8.3.0-r0)
(10/26) Installing gcc (8.3.0-r0)
ERROR: gcc-8.3.0-r0: BAD archive
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/231#issuecomment-319008320  ? Basically try using `apk add --update --no-cache gcc` instead? As to why, maybe a server side issue?

Comment: Didn't solve the issue @Perplexabot